# Read csv file but it got \ufeff in first column name, How to remove it in Robot Framework

Tags: csv, robotframework

I had saved CSV by use CSV UTF-8 (Comma Delimited) for file type because it supports Thai language.

- Example Data

[image]

Example Code

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           CSVLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Test CSV
   @{dict}=    read csv file to associative  ${CURDIR}/../TestData/Data.csv
   Log   ${dict}
   Log to console  &{dict[${2}]}[Empty]${SPACE}&{dict[${2}]}[CustFname]${SPACE}&{dict[${2}]}[CustLname]
```

- Actual Result

[image]

The robot was not found Empty's column because the Robot input \ufeff in front of column name (\ufeffEmpty) and it happens only first column, Can Anyone help me please? Now I fix this problem by 
 doesn't use the first column.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, however, these are the stpes i would do as part of debugging the issue, you can arrive at the root cause of the issue by doing the following mentioned below,

Verify whether you can read the created CSV file successfully without making use of the library first, as shown in the below code. If this is not the case, then, your csv file is containing some issue, which you have to fix first.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Verify UTF-8 FROM CSV
    CREATE CSVFILE WITH UTF8
    READ CSVFILE

*** Keywords ***
CREATE CSVFILE WITH UTF8
    Create File    C:/csvtest/test.csv    name,userid,firstname,lastname,dob,doj,status    encoding=UTF-8

READ CSVFILE
    ${Test}    Get File    C:/csvtest/test.csv    encoding=UTF-8    encoding_errors=strict
    LOG TO CONSOLE      ${Test}
```